# « Être dans les patates » : locutions avec thématique similaire pour souligner l'erreur etc. ?

Tags: québec, locutions, régionalismes, belgique

La « [patate](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/patate) » pour dire la *pomme de terre* est un sens qui prend forme au Canada en [1765](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=389&rubrique=) sous l'influence anglaise, avant d'apparaître en 1769 en français d'Europe (tr. fam.). À l'expression québécoise « *être dans les patates* », on trouve : "« perdu » (Cf. *dans les choux*)."<sup>1</sup> Ailleurs on [trouve](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=411&rubrique=orig) plutôt (extraits; mes commentaires entre crochets) :

> **patates (être dans les ~) (loc. verb.)**
>  Fig. (Par métaphore). Fam. Être dans l'erreur, se tromper, divaguer.
>  Innovation
>   lexématique, syntagmatique, phraséologique à partir du français du
>   Québec.
>  Depuis 1882. Ne paraît pas avoir eu cours en français
>   d'Europe au sens d' «être dans l'erreur»; voir cependant les sens
>   [28](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=412&rubrique=orig).[vieilli - être dans les ~, somnolence alcool.], [29](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=413&rubrique=orig).[vieilli - tomber ~, s’évanouir] et [30](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=414&rubrique=orig).[vieux - tomber ~, précarité financière].
>
> [ Ces trois entrées contenant des références à *Bruxelles*; par exemple, le sens 28 : « Depuis 1898. Cp.
>   en français de Bruxelles être dans les patates «être dans les pommes»
>   (v. BaetBrux 420) qui permet de suggérer l'hypothèse d'une origine
>   européenne de l'expression québécoise. » ]
>
> *Aristote, un niochon qui a vécu trois cents ans avant Notre-Seigneur [...] prétend que la base de la politique est l'honnêteté et la
>   justice. Le pauvre homme était dans les patates.* 
>  [1882, *Le
>   Grognard*, Montréal, 27 mai, p. 2. [presse, journaux, périodiques]]
>
> [ *Base de données lexicographiques panfrancophone (BDLP)* - « *patate, être dans les ~* » ]

En résumé, si le mot *patate* vient du Québec, un ancien sens de cette expression l'utilisant peut avoir trouvé son origine d'une autre expression provenant du français d'Europe. D'autre part, à mon sens, il y a certains points communs que partagent l'idée d'être perdu, des propos « tenus » dans un état de conscience altéré ou de somnolence, ou celle d'être dans l'erreur. Il s'agit à plusieurs égards d'[*errer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/errer) en [*radotant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/radoter), pourrait-on dire en « ratissant large »<sup>2</sup>; errer de manière à susciter l'étonnement et à autoriser parfois même d'interrompre l'interlocuteur par un commentaire au sujet de son point de vue...

---

Existe-t-il dans la francophonie d'autres *locutions (verbales)* basées sur une métaphore « *agricole/botanique/du terroir* » et qui serviraient les mêmes fins que de dire à quelqu'un « *tu es dans les patates* » (exprimer que l'autre se trompe, divague, est perdu, ou délire par son propos etc.) ? (On peut aussi aller plus loin avec le *chou*, ou la fameuse *pomme* de Belgique.)

---

<sub>1. *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous la dir. d'A. Rey, *ed. Le Robert*. Sauf qu'au *TLFi*, on a, pour « *être dans les [choux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/choux)* » : *[[ê]tre le dernier d'un classement*. Le *DHLF* explique plutôt à *dans les choux* : « être dans l'embarras, en difficulté » puis on y mentionne les applications successives (typographes en précarité, comédiens, lycéens, sportifs éliminés) avant d'inviter la comparaison avec l'allemand (*Kraute gehen*) et l'italien (*andare a ingrassare i cavoli*). Au final je ne comprends pas parfaitement la référence à *perdu* et au *chou*, ni si c'est être égaré au propre ou au figuré, ou dans le sens d'*avoir perdu* qqc. .</sub>

<sub>2. Le [*Wiktionnaire*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_dans_les_patates) propose une référence à l'automobile dans l'étymologie de l'expression. Mais l'automobile est-elle répandue en 1882, à la campagne, au Québec ? On enregistre 45 véhicules à Montréal en [1904](http://bilan.usherbrooke.ca/bilan/pages/collaborations/8504.html). De plus, à [*être dans le champ*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_dans_le_champ) : on ne note pas que le *TLFi* mentionne à (prendre/aller) « à travers [champs](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/champs) », que « [c]ette expr. a pu s'employer au fig. à l'époque class., signifiant : d'une manière désordonnée, en divaguant (cf. [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/champ)). ». L'expression avec au *champ gauche* au baseball reste intéressante; normalement on ne vise pas le champ gauche, le viser est inusité ou surprenant.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Que penses-tu de l'expression suivante :

> Il ne faut pas pousser mémé dans les orties !

Elle exprime que l'autre exagère, qu'il se trompe.

Source sur [expressio.fr](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/faut-pas-pousser-meme-memere-grand-mere-dans-les-orties.php)

Comment: Perso j'aurais tendance à te rejoindre sur l'idée d'exagération, d'abus, mais pas vraiment de se tromper ni de divaguer

Comment: Pour moi divaguer veut dire que l'on n'est pas en phase avec la réalité, exagérer peut avoir la même définition.

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec, lorsqu on se trompe on est dans le champ.

Comment: dans le champ de patates?